# Working with quickly, are there any gtk.Builder code sketching tools that integrate?

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, glade

Example:

```
quickly create ubuntu-application testing
quickly design
#makes changes
#insert some other command here that would be roughly equivalent to 'quickly sketch'
quickly edit
#to populate the sketched functions
```

Willing to accept other gtk.Builder solutions that work if they're demonstrated/screenshots with a quickly generated ui/xml pair.

In this context what I mean by code sketching and the desired effect would be `quickly sketch` results in empty functions being created in the appropriate files instead of capturing stderr on `quickly run` and adding them, then populating them.

A simple example, add a button in `quickly design`.  It will still launch with `quickly run` as you expect.  Something I miss from wxglade is the code-sketching for new buttons/etc.

Might be more of a glade/gtk.Builder question than a quickly question.

In response to the answer, I opened a whishlist bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+bug/978266).

I also started working on a project I'm calling simply.  The first bits of code are [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1134362/).  It includes simple code-sketching of callbacks.

Comment: Can you explain what quickly sketch should do?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad - does that make more sense?

Comment: Awesome!  Would love to see it. Thanks for the bug report/wishlist item in launchpad.  Added myself as affected.

Comment: @IanB.  I wrote a simple sketcher that works with glade, but doesn't really integrate with quickly.  I'll post code when I get home.

Comment: @aking1012... still interested in seeing that code if you get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: @IanB. - added a link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be nice. It shouldn't be too difficult to implement either, since the handlers are defined in the ui-file. I don't know of any tools that does it now. I don't think it could be done in the GUI designer, since it's language independent. But adding a 'sketch' command to  Quickly should be possible. If you add a wishlist bug to Quickly, perhaps someone can get around to it? I might want to have that myself.

https://launchpad.net/quickly