# how to set ubuntu not to group the similar windows when swithing through the open windows?

Tags: window

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LST

I want the Ubuntu `not to group the open windows when I am using Alt+Tab` looking for the window I want. What shoud I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just let them group and use special commands for them?
In [How to ungroup windows on task switcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123977/how-to-ungroup-windows-on-task-switcher) you got:

Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>) (by glindste)

or

Press <kbd>↓</kbd> while holding <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to view list of windows for current application. (by Riateche)

I guess it's duplicate question, I'm new here, I don't know what to do with it.