# Ungroup items in taskbar

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, taskbar

Because I opened loads of files by accident, I somehow found the option to group similar types together.
How do you undo this? See screenshot for example of what grouping does. Right-clicking doesn't work. I can't find any option in the display preferences or system settings.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I didn't find an answer but at least you can ALT+TAB through the windows with Compiz (see similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/123977/how-to-ungroup-windows-on-task-switcher )

Comment: After upgrading to 14.04 the problem remains. This is becoming hugely annoying now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found how to do it. In the left most corner of the taskbar, right click and "Preferences" appears. From here you can change the options.[image]