# How to never ungroup windows of the same app in Task Switcher

Tags: 16.04, application-switcher

In Ubuntu 16.04 when an app is focused on long enough in the application switcher it will present me with all the windows of that app.  How do I configure the switcher to never do this?

Comment: Clarification: Have you tried any solution from [this older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/123977/37165)? If any of those answers works, then this question could be a duplicate.

Comment: It seems the asker wants the opposite of that question.

Comment: So "never ungroup windows" would actually mean "don't reveal individual windows in the group windows"? That is one tricky question. This is a unique question then, +1.

Comment: @clearkimura yes, I want the opposite of the linked question.  I read the answers anyway, just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could install Unity Tweak Tool using

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Launch the application, go to **Switcher** and uncheck the checkbox which reads **Automatically expose windows**.

Comment: Let me try it for a couple of hours before I award the bounty.

Comment: Bounty awarded.