# How do I move clock to the right end of GNOME 3 Panel from the middle?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, panel, gnome-shell, clock

How do I move the clock to the right of the panel in Ubuntu GNOME?

In other words, I want the clock to be in the same place as in Ubuntu Unity 16.04.

Comment: If you think this feature to be customizable directly in GNOME, please [vote for it](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/931).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Frippery Move Clock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2/move-clock/) to achieve this goal.

Also another extension called [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/)

> [...] makes a few layout tweaks to the top panel and removes window decorations to make it look like Ubuntu Unity Shell.

Moving the clock to the right is among the modifications it does.

Comment: This is such a basic customization that there shouldn't need to be multiple extensions for it. Please [vote for GNOME to implement this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/931).

Answer (score 14):

Here is how I did it (on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS):

1. Launch 'Ubuntu Software' which is built in Ubuntu 18.04.
2. Install 'Dash to Panel' shell extension from 'Add-ons' -> 'Shell Extensions'. Scroll down to find the 'Dash to Panel' extension and install it.
3. Press 'Extension Settings', find the settings button of the 'Dash to Panel' in the menu.
4. Open the configuration settings of 'Dash to Panel' and find the 'Position and Style' tab. On this tab you would find the  'Clock Location' configuration. Change this to 'Right of status menu'.

This would work. However, the side-effect (desired effect in my case) is that the 'Top panel' and the default Ubuntu 'dock' would merge together to form a single panel just like in the Windows OS.

Comment: This is the answer. Tried several extensions before this, but all they did was move the clock to the leftmost end of the right panel area. That's not what I wanted. I want the clock to be at the extreme end. Just like in unity, or osx, or windows.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `Extend Panel Menu` which is found at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/

Answer (score 4):

as of Ubuntu 22 and Gnome 42, the Gnome extension "just perfection" lets you adjust the position of the clock to be left, middle or right.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/

EDIT:
(Off-topic: and if you want to tweak your clock, "Date Menu Formatter" is my choice)
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4655/date-menu-formatter/

Comment: As written this is an answer for Ubuntu Core as it is the only version of Ubuntu that is simply called 22.