# How do I customize the date/time display in GNOME Shell's top bar?

Tags: gnome-shell, date, top-bar

Time indicator is shown as `"%a %H:%M"` in the *center* of the top bar.

How do I move it back to the right where it belongs, and make it include the full date and time (`"%Y-%m-%d %s %H:%M"`)?

Comment: Not a regression if you're comparing oranges with tangerines. It is as always has been in Gnome which is now the default DE instead of Unity.

Comment: I would recommend removing the last paragraph (reason: what MichaelBay said) and change the title to something like "How do I change the position and format of date & time in top bar of Ubuntu 17.10?" as it's not "*wrong*", that's how it is in GNOME.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may achieve your goal using some [GNOME shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions).

#### Moving clock to the right

You may use [Frippery Move Clock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2/move-clock/).

See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960597/how-do-i-move-clock-to-the-right-of-panel-in-ubuntu-gnome) for more options.

#### Changing date & time format

You may use [Clock override](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/). It lets you

> Override the Gnome Shell clock with a new time format or text of your choice.

It supports [Python's `strftime` format](http://strftime.org/) (so you'll be able to set your preferred `"%Y-%m-%d %s %H:%M"` format to display).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Panel Date Format](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1462/panel-date-format/) is another GNOME Shell extension that allows you to modify the formatting of date and time in the top panel, e.g. to include the current week number.

I used

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/panel-date-format/format "'%a (KW %V) %d.%m.%y %H:%M'"
```

to display below format:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another place to look:- 
Ubuntu Software Centre - certainly in Ubuntu 17.10.
If you search for "clock" a whole list of different programs is displayed, Clock Override among them.

Comment: I realize this is an old question but it's quite relevant to a question I answered recently.  The customization of the formatting of the Gnome 3 top bar clock to your liking can be cleanly achieved through gnome shell localization/internationalization configuration without extensions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096203/how-to-display-custom-formatted-clock-in-top-bar-on-multiple-displays-in-ubuntu