# In Ubuntu 17.10 and later how do I change the clock to a 12 hour format?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, time, clock

In Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME, how do I change the clock to a 12 hour format? And maybe for a more difficult rhetorical question, why does Ubuntu feel compelled to hide such basic functionality?

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, that was not done by Ubuntu, but by GNOME developers.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Click on *Activities* and search for "Settings" and launch it. Click on *Details* at the bottom of the sidebar and then select "*Date & Time*".

You'll find an option to change the time format.

[image]

---

For an option with more customisations, you may use a GNOME shell extension called "[Clock Override](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/)" as mentioned in [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/968955/).

Comment: Confirmed, works in `Ubuntu 18.04` also.

Comment: Why would they put this under "Details"?? What does clock have to do with details?  This whole new settings user interface is just trash.

Comment: You can also just search for `Date & Time` to find the setting directly, at least in 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

In search bar, search for "Time" and the "Date & Time" setting comes up, click on it and change to "AM/PM".