# Show year in date time in top panel

Tags: panel, ubuntu-mate, dconf

I am trying to get the year to display in my top panel. The %Y should show it but it does not.

```
%a %b %d %Y, %I:%p
```

Comment: does everything else work (ie `%a %b....`)? have you tried `%y` or just `%Y` ?(just for testing)

Comment: @j-money
Yes everything else works. Even %y does not work.

Comment: Do they work alone? without all the other flags

Comment: @j-money I do not understand your question.

Comment: Get rid of `%a %b %d , %I:%p `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I customize the date/time display in GNOME Shell's top bar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968860/how-do-i-customize-the-date-time-display-in-gnome-shells-top-bar)

Comment: @george It seems OP uses MATE instead of GNOME from the tags.

Comment: @j-money Why would I get rid of my time format? It seems like some foks forget that not everyone uses gnome.