# Stop alt-tab from grouping windows using unity on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a similar problem to [How to ungroup windows on Unity task switcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123977/how-to-ungroup-windows-on-unity-task-switcher)

However none of the solutions worked for me. It still does the annoying behavior where when I alt-tab, multiple terminal windows get bunched up and I have to start hitting ` to switch between them. I want it to be more like on windows where it just goes through each open window.

I am on unity 7.5.0 on ubuntu 20.04. I've tried to replicate all the combinations in the question I linked to but I have not managed to succeed. If I press windows key/super and type "keyboard" to effect the keyboard shortcuts, I have "Switch applications" disabled. In ccsm I have "application switcher" disabled, and on "static application switcher", I have alt tab as "next window (all windows)" instead of just "next window". I did this both with and without sudo. Strangely, I have the exact same config on a different computer (also unity on ubuntu 20.04) and it works as intended, and I'm not sure what is different.

Comment: In Compiz Config Settings manager, you can change to a Window switcher for Alt+tab rather than the default Application switcher.

Comment: I set the shortcut for next window (all windows) in the static application switcher in ccsm if that's what you mean. Didn't seem to change anything